# Delay wifimanager connection to wifi

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, wifimanager

I am using wifimanager in a project. I set custom parameters but once it connects to the wifi I can't set these parameters again. I could reset the wifi credentials but I would rather it waited 20-30 seconds with the portal before connecting to the wifi. Is this possible?

I have tried `wifiManager.setConfigPortalTimeout(30);` prior to `wifiManager.autoConnect` but this does not seem to work.

Comment: you can always start the wifimanager server with `startConfigPortal`

Comment: This seems to need configuring every boot? Kinda need to continue if there is no intervention within the 30 seconds.

Comment: I have a project done here: https://github.com/JAndrassy/SunriseClock/blob/main/SunriseClock/SunriseClock.ino

Comment: ahhh setConfigPortalTimeout(); then wifiManager.startConfigPortal(); you are a legend thanks.